# Web worker - scroll to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a long running web worker that continually  produces output that is displayed in the browser. Is it possible to have the browser automatically scroll to the bottom of the page such that the last output remains visible?

Comment: Should not be doable from within the web worker since it has no idea of the DOM. Maybe you could listen for changes to the element in which the content is added and scroll the element on content update?

Comment: This scrolls to the bottom of the div, but doesn't affect the scroll bar of the window.

Comment: Can't you just do document.scrollTop = document.scrollHeight; when you append to the DOM

Comment: It should do. It's only inside the worker itself that can't access the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.scrollTop = body.scrollHeight;
```